# Java User input YY-MM-DD format

Tags: java, regex, string, date, comparison

This is for an assignment in data structures and I can't seem to find the exact answer I need.

I am attempting to take user input for a date, preferably YY-MM-DD format, then check for validity.. if not valid, cycling until valid.  This really seems very tedious and I am receiving two illegal starts of expression errors.

I did a search on Google and StackOverflow, but only find things addressing Date

```
public String hireDate(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean answer = false;
    while(answer == false){
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        if((temp.charAt(0) >= 0 && temp.charAt(0) <= 9) && (temp.charAt(1)
                >= 0 && temp.charAt(1) <= 9) && (temp.charAt(2) == -) 
                && (temp.charAt(3) >= 0 && temp.charAt(3) <= 9) && (temp.charAt(4)
                >= 0 && temp.charAt(4) <= 9) && (temp.charAt(5) == -)
                && (temp.charAt(6) >= 0 && temp.charAt(6) <= 9)){
            answer = true;
        } else {
            answer = false;
        }    
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: In any specific programming language? Please add appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with Regex. Just check if your input string matches your pattern (YY-MM-DD)

```
if (temp.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp.charAt(1)>=0
```

You are comparing a character to an integer.